# Anonymous users cannot register for a civievent

Tags: civievent

CiviCRM 4.7.6 and Drupal 7.43.
I created a CiviEvent and enabled online registration. I can access the registration page when logged in as the administrator but anonymous users get this error message:

The requested Profile (gid=12) is disabled OR it is not configured to be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings.

Drupal permissions for anonymous include CiviCRM: profile listings and forms, CiviCRM: profile view, CiviCRM: access all custom data, CiviCRM: view all activities, CiviEvent: register for events, CiviEvent: view event info.

Comment: Pls clarify what the settings are for the Profile and check what the Fields that you are selecting to show in the profile are being used for eg Event, Contact, Member, etc.

Comment: The fields are being used for Standalone Form or Directory, CiviEvent, CiviEvent_Additional. I'm not sure what additional info you need. I don't understand how profiles relate to CiviEvent. On a different site all I needed to do was create the event and enable online registration. Everything worked fine in that case. Profiles never entered the picture.

Comment: To clarify, it is the Profile that is used as Standalone Form etc. What I was trying to ask was what the fields on the Profile were used for, eg Contacts, Events, Participants etc. But your latter reply suggests that that is not the issue any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an Event you specify what Profiles should show eg at http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/manage/registration?reset=1&action=update&id=3 you can see it has Include Profile = Your Registration Info.

In this case it sounds like you have some other Profiles in use (instead or as well)

And either those Profiles are "not configured to be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings" - which is what your error says - or the Profile might have incompatible fields included in it.

Comment: OK, after looking at the configuration for the CiviEvent in question I see that it includes the Your Registration Info profile. That profile is used for CiviEvent so I don't think that is the issue. Now, for some unknown reason, anonymous users can now register if they use Chrome, Safari, or Opera. However, the error message mentioned above is displayed when the Firefox browser is used.

Comment: if this is a public form then you could provide the link in your question so people can see the problem first hand.

Comment: You can see the problem here [http://indiancreeknaturecenter.us](http://indiancreeknaturecenter.us). In the right sidebar chose "Register Now".

Comment: I tried registering for "Birding at the Nature Center" on both chrome and ff and i got no messages indicating problems ie i got "Thank You for Registering. Your registration has been processed successfully. Please print this page for your records." However i do note that your images are not showing as their link is to localhost, but that is a separate question for you to ask (you see a missing image icon in chrome but not in ff) (http://localhost:8888/indiancreeknaturecenter/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/warbler.jpg)

Comment: so there will be 2 registrations that need cancelling - both have fuzion.co.nz in their email address - hope that was okay to do.

Comment: This is strange. I am able to register with firefox when I use my PC laptop. When I use my Mac I get the error message mentioned above. I've cleared the FF cache on the Mac and the problem persists. Anyway, I corrected the path to the images. Thanks for the heads-up on that. Also, I've removed your registration to the "Birding at the Nature Center" event. It promises to be a good time. We'll miss you!

Comment: One final note, after uninstalling and reinstalling FireFox the error message is gone and I can register for events.